# How to use a static C variable across multiple files?

Tags: c, file, gcc, static

I have two C files 1.c and 2.c

### 2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

static int i;

int func1(){
   i = 5;
   printf("\nfile2 : %d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

### 1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i;

int main()
{
   func1();
   printf("\nFile1: %d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled both the files with "gcc 1.c 2.c -o st"
The output is as follows

```
file2 : 5

File2: 0
```

I was expecting output as follows

```
file2 : 5

File2: 5
```

I want to access the same variable "i" in both the files.
How can I do it?

Comment: You can't have two `main()` functions.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I edited the question

Comment: Define your variable in one cpp file and in another use keyword *extern*.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. The whole point of declaring a file scope variable as static is to _prevent_ it from getting accessed by other files. What you should have asked yourself is "why am I using static in my code, when I have no idea about the meaning of the keyword"

Comment: You can use extern instead of static.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Choose one file which will store the variable. Do not use `static`. The whole point of `static` is to keep the variable private and untouchable by other modules.

In all other files, use the `extern` keyword to reference the variable:

```
extern int i;
```

Comment: I changed the declaration in 1.c to "extern int i;" /tmp/cc6ZXXhV.o: In function `main':
1.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `i'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If I remove static would it will be a global variable. It won't be static anymore.

Comment: static variables cannot be referenced from outside their compilation unit. You need a global variable.

Comment: The only way to do what you want _is_ a global variable. That is the point of _global_ : It's the same for every module.

Comment: Ok. So now I got it. The static and global variable works same if we want to use it across files? Am I understanding correct?

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi: No static and global are orthogonal. You just can't use a `static` variable across files.

Comment: _static_ means it is local to the file, you won't be able to access it anywhere else except in your file. _extern_ means the variable is stored in another file, it is a _global_ variable

Comment: A static variable cannot be used across files. Note that 'static' when applied to C variables means something entirely different from C++ or Java static member variables.

Comment: If I use a static variable across files, its different only in compilation time. After I finish compilation it will be single executable. What will be the difference If I have used it as static or global?

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi If you try to use a static variable across files, you will end up having different variables, one for each file, which have all the same name.

Comment: Just curious how does C++ handles this

Answer (score 6):

There is never a reason to access a static variable in another file. You don't seem to know why you are using the static keyword. There are two ways to declare variables at file scope (outside functions).

**Global variable**

```
int i;
```

Advantages:

- is valid throughout the whole program execution.

Disadvantages:

- can be accessed with **extern** to create spaghetti code.
- "Pollutes" the global namespace.
- Not thread-safe.
- Initialized at program startup, which creates program overhead.

---

**Local/private variable**

```
static int i;
```

Advantages:

- is valid throughout the whole program execution.
- Can only be accessed by files in the same "module"/"translation unit" (same .c file).
- Provides private encapsulation since it cannot be accessed by the caller.

Disadvantages:

- Not thread-safe.
- Initialized at program startup, which creates program overhead.

---

My personal opinion is that there is never a reason to use global variables nor the extern keyword. I have been programming for 15+ years and never needed to use either. I have programmed everything from realtime embedded systems to Windows GUI fluff apps and I have never needed to use global variables in any form of application. Furthermore, they are banned in pretty much every single known C coding standard.

Comment: > "There is never a reason to access a static variable in another file"

There is: to split a module across different files.

Answer (score 1):

`static` variables can only be accessed within a single translation unit, which means that only code in the file that it is defined in can see it. The [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) has a nice explanation. In this situation, to share the variable across multiple files you would use `extern`.

Comment: I tried using extern keyword in file 1.c. But its throwing compilation error. It does not recognize the external variable "i"

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommended, but we can achieve it using pointers with extern storage class.

**In 2.c**

```
static int i;
int *globalvar = &i;
```

**In 1.c**

```
extern int *globalvar;
```

Comment: This is helpful, I got this question many times in interviews and now I know the hack.