# define constants in a struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a struct with some constants in it like this:

```
#include <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
...
struct properties {
    //Volume control
    const AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume = {
        kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, //mSelector
        kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput, //mScope
        0 //mElement
    };
    //Mute control
    const AudioObjectPropertyAddress mute = { 
        kAudioDevicePropertyMute,
        kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
        0
    };
};
```

However, I cannot access the constants in this class;

```
//Function used to for example set volume level or set mute status
//bool setProperty(UInt32 data_to_write, AudioObjectPropertyAddress addr_to_write_to);
//Following line should mute the system audio
setProperty(1, properties::mute);
```

This will make the compiler return the following error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static data member 'mute'
```

So, I tried making the constants static like this:

```
const static AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume = { ...
```

But now, I get a different error:

```
error: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const AudioObjectPropertyAddress' requires 'constexpr' specifier
```

The last thing I tried is changing `const static` to `static constexpr`, however again, I cannot access the constants. Every time I try to access them, the compiler show this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "properties::mute", referenced from:
      _main in main-fefb9f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I'm not really sure what's going on here, I tried converting my struct into a class, but I ended up getting the same `Undefined symbols` error.
I know I could just define the two constants as global variables, but I thought putting them into a struct/class would make the code look "nicer" or just more organized.
Could someone please explain what's wrong here and provide a possible solution?

Comment: I believe that the requirement to give static struct/class members a placement outside of their enclosing struct/class definition came from legacy expectations where structs are inside of headers, thus even their definition could occur multiple times in multiple "compilation units". I expect this requirement to be removed eventually once C++20 modules become the main factor of C++ libraries/modularity.

Comment: I don't see static in the first code block so it may have been missing when going to constexpr as well.  Some classes may be incompatible with {} in the way you are using them- for example if they contain unions, you can only set some members.  Provide what the members are or verify that your ={} works as intended in a simpler context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ```
    struct properties {
        //Volume control
        const AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume = {
            kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, //mSelector
            kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput, //mScope
            0 //mElement
        };
    };
  ```

  is valid, but `volume` is not a static member, so usage requires an instance:

  ```
  setProperty(1, properties{}.volume);
  ```
- With `static const`, it would be:

  ```
  struct properties {
      //Volume control
      static const AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume;
  };

  const properties::AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume {
      kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, //mSelector
      kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput, //mScope
      0 //mElement
  };
  ```

  and usage might be the expected:

  ```
  setProperty(1, properties::volume);
  ```
- with `static constexpr` in C++11/C++14:

  ```
  struct properties {
      //Volume control
      static constexpr AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume{
          kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, //mSelector
          kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput, //mScope
          0 //mElement
      };
  };

  const properties::AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume; // Definition when ODR-used
  ```
- with `static /*inline*/ constexpr` since C++17:

  ```
  struct properties {
      //Volume control
      static /*inline*/ constexpr AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume{
          kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, //mSelector
          kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput, //mScope
          0 //mElement
      };
  };
  ```

Answer (score 1):

why not just properties.volume and properties.mute or use namespace otherwise...

```
namespace properties 
{
    //Volume control
    const AudioObjectPropertyAddress volume = {
        kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, //mSelector
        kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput, //mScope
        0 //mElement
    };

    //Mute control
    const AudioObjectPropertyAddress mute = { 
        kAudioDevicePropertyMute,
        kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
        0
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of things you can try:

You could.... redesign your templating/types. [Struct vs Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614314/when-to-use-a-namespace-or-a-struct). Without seeing the whole project its tough to guide in a specific direction. Its up to you to decide if you need to use a struct, enum, namespace, class to encapsulate your code.

As for const static declaration. [Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141950/initializing-const-member-within-class-declaration-in-c) describing valid methods of static class membder declarations. Pay close attention to your c++ version.

> "Prior to C++11, only static const data members of integral or
> enumeration type could have initializers in the class definition."

Lastly, the static constexpr undefined. Is your static var in the same header/source file as where you are calling it? (Likely not, as the error shows the call from main). [Static variables are not visible to other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728426/how-to-use-a-static-c-variable-across-multiple-files).

If you want to modify static vars you could do so using a public get/set from a class function.

Suppose 'mute' is a single uint8_t value. Consider using a namespace with all static data declared as: static const uint8_t mute.